# How to do .NET Core remote development with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: linux, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging

Is it possible to develop and build a .NET Core application locally, then push it to a remote Linux system, run it there and attach the remote debugger?

Can I execute a run script from within Visual Studio which does all the tasks via SSH? (I'm thinking of something similiar to run configuration "Shell Script" in Intellij IDE.)

I'm aware of Visual Studio Code and the remote development extension, but I'm not a fan of that IDE.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-dotnet-core-linux-with-ssh?view=vs-2019

Answer (score -3):

If you're thinking of something like what you could do with Java in for example Netbeans, or c++ for linux in Visual Studio, then you can't do that easily/ as conveniently with .NET core and linux unfortunately.

Comment: This is just not true